# fortran compile blas program error

Tags: matrix, compilation, fortran, blas

I am new to BLAS and trying to compile my Fortran program that uses BLAS for matrix-matrix multiplication. I have two matrices A and B.

```
integer, parameter :: RK = selected_real_kind(10,2)
real(kind=RK),pointer :: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)
```

then I put some random values into it and try to multiply:

```
  call dgemm('N', 'N', N, N, N, 1.0_RK, 
        A, N, B, N, 0.0_RK, C, N)
```

N is the size of both matrices. Are all parameters correct?

I cannot compile and get following error:

```
  call dgemm('N', 'N', N, N, N, 1.0_RK, 
                                        1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
matrixmul.F90:44.2:

  A, N, B, N, 0.0_RK, C, N)
  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

What is the problem? Should I compile with some specified BLAS flag? I have installed BLAS as [explained here](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Template:Installing_BLAS_and_LAPACK).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just continue on a new line in Fortran, you must designate the end of the line for continuation:

```
 call dgemm('N', 'N', N, N, N, 1.0_RK, &
        A, N, B, N, 0.0_RK, C, N)
```

In the fixed form you put whatever in the sixth column on the new line instead.

There is no special BLAS flag, you only have to tell the linker you want to link with the BLAS library. On my operating system it is done by `-lblas` or `-lmkl` or similar.

Comment: Thans! Now I compile with -lblas and have another error: matrixmul.F90:(.text+0x592): undefined reference to `dgemm_'. How can I verify that BLAS is installed?

Comment: search for `libblas.so` or `libblas.a` or `blas.dll` What OS do you have?

Comment: My OS - Ubuntu 12.04 and after search I have:/etc/alternatives/libblas.a
/usr/lib/libblas.a
/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.a, which indicats that library is installed.

Comment: They definitely have the BLAS package in the standard repositories, just us your package manager. Try Synaptic or `apt get blas`.

Comment: You can also add /usr/lib/libblas.a in the compilation command: `gfortran /usr/lib/libblas.a program.f90`